# Scroll down to show header and hide when scroll up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I tried to make a header animation like this website: https://www.templatemonster.com/demo/57969.html
And here are my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="header-part" class="container-fluid fixed-nav">  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header-part.container-fluid { 
background-color: #1f2324;
padding: 32px 0 22px 0;
display: flex;
height: 100px;
 width: 100%;
padding: 0;
}

#header-part.fixed-nav {
position: fixed;
top: -100px;
border-bottom: 0px solid #5f6a6d;
z-index: 4;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(window).scroll( function(){
 var top_of_window = $(window).scrollTop();
 if( top_of_window > 100 ){
  $(".fixed-nav").animate({top:'0'}, 800);
  }
});
```

My idea is used `top:-100px` to hide it and show it when scrolling down to 100px. It runs smoothly but when I add `else {$(".fixed-nav").animate({top:'-100px'}, 800);}` to hide it when scroll up above 100px, it hide my header as by default and maybe `if` is ignored to run `else`.

Try it, then remove comment of `else` in file js to see problem
https://github.com/dothuan96/Animation-HTML-basic/tree/master/cinema%20header

Comment: and what error you got ?

Comment: My header still at `top: -100px` even I scroll it. I think `if` command be ignored and `else` run keep my header still at `top:-100px`

Comment: can you show us a complete working code with the if else you wrote ? so we can reproduce

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j0yxz1fa/

Comment: The issue cannot be reproduced, as demonstrated in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/105hje83/ (console.log functionality added for real-time evaluation of variables)

Comment: there is no `fixed-nav` element in your HTML

Comment: Here is your updated JSFiddle --> https://jsfiddle.net/j0yxz1fa/2/ Always remember to include any javascript framework or library (like jQuery) that you intend to work with.

Comment: But when I scroll up to above 100px, the header still not hide :(

Comment: @ThuanDo are you sure? Check again ( jsfiddle.net/j0yxz1fa/2), and be patient - there is a delay.

Comment: I have up all file of my work above. You can download and see its problem.

Comment: @ThuanDo Sorry, but no. All code required to reproduce the issue should be included in the question itself, this is a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example, read through: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve The external example you've included in the form of a JSFiddle has been shown to work, and another separate JSFiddle demonstration (based off the initial code provided in the question) has also been shown to work as intended.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
if( top_of_window > 100 ){
  $(".fixed-nav").animate({height: 'toggle'}, 800);
  }
else{ 
$(".fixed-nav").animate({
            height: 'toggle', 
        800
        });
}
```

Comment: sorry about my grammar, I have changed it to `top:112` but it still not run correctly.

Comment: i just added a new method

Comment: @jasinthpremkumar check this https://jsfiddle.net/psruj73b/ .. your answer is incorrect we can use "-100px"